# Simple function returning 1 if the Mean = Mode, or 0 if not

Tags: javascript, beginner, statistics

I'm trying to get better at javascript and have built a simple function that returns 1 if the mode is equal to the mean, and 0 if not. You can enter an array of numbers into the function:

```
// tests
meanMode([1,2,3]); - returns 0
meanMode([4,4,4,6,2]); - returns 1
meanMode([4,4,4,6,6,6,2]); - returns 0
```

To clarify, the mean is the middle number in the array, and mode most occurring number.

When I was writing this, I wondered whether I create too many variables and overcomplicate things. The problems I thought I might be making are:

1. There are too many variables
2. It's confusing and over complex
3. It can be hard to retrace my logic and know what the code does and why it's there

I have a few questions that I hope better coders than myself can answer, as I'm relatively new to javascript:

1. Was using a counts variable necessary?
2. Are all variable keywords (const & let) optimal?
3. Is it wise to include comments to describe what the code does?
4. Was declaring the mode variable before assigning its value the best way? Its value depends on a condition

Before writing this I wrote a brief logic plan as follows:

Mode:

1. var uniqueVals with unique vals (set)
2. for each unique value (uniqueVals.map), count no of occurrences in arr (filter.length) & store as an array
3. if all values are identical, return 0, otherwise get the most frequent & store in variable (there may be cases with no mode)

Mean:

1. sum all numbers
2. divide by no of numbers

And:

- if unique values length is same as arr length, return 0
- if mean = mode, return 1

When people write programming, is it usually best to have a detailed plan to follow? I wonder whether there are any best practices that I could follow to improve my coding ability.

```
function meanMode(arr) {
    let uniqueVals = Array.from(new Set(arr));
    let counts = uniqueVals.map(function (c, i, a) {
        return arr.filter(function (c2) {
            return c2 == c
        }).length
    }); // [3,1,1]

    if (arr.every(sameValues)) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        var mode;

        // if highest number in counts appears just once, then there is a mode
        if ((counts.filter(function (x) { return x == (Math.max(...counts)) }).length) == 1) {
            mode = uniqueVals[counts.indexOf(Math.max(...counts))]; // scope issue?
        } else {
            return 0;
        }

        const mean = (arr.reduce(function (a, c) { return a + c })) / (arr.length);

        if (mode == mean) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    function sameValues(c, i, a) {
        return c == a[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I don’t think this is reasonable:

> if unique values length is same as arr length, return 0

If your array consists of unique values only (e.g. `[1, 2, 3, 4]`), its mode is not unique, rather there is multiple modes (in this case `[1, 2, 3, 4]`). How you define what *mode* exactly means depends on your application so I’m going to ignore this for now.

---

Let’s look at your code. I’ll list some observations:

- **Function name**. A name like `meanEqualsMode` would more clearly describe what the function does
- **Unused variables**. There are a few unused variables. Line 3 uses three arguments for the `map` function’s callback, but the callback is only ever called with one argument: The current array element. You also never use `i` and `a`.
- **Single-letter variable names**. This style of naming problematic for a variety of reasons. Most importantly, it’s harder to reason about your own code. For example, in line 21, the `reduce` function has `a` and `c` as callback arguments. `sum` and `count` would be better names.
- **Separation of concerns**. Your `meanMode` function does multiple things. It calculates the mode *and* the mean. Instead, use separate functions to calculate the mode and mean separately. If your applications uses the check for equality of mode and mean a lot, this would be a third function calling the other two. I’ve done that in the updated code below.
- **Predictable results**. You state that `meanMode` should return whether the mode and the mean are equal; however, it actually returns a `Number` (`1` or `0`). A comparison function (e.g. a function containing the words *is*, *equal*, or similar) should always return a boolean value (`true` or `false`). This again makes it easier to reason about your code. Just reading `meanEqualsMode([2, 3, 5])` should tell you what the result of that function will be without the need to look at the actual implementation.

```
function meanEqualsMode(array) {
  const mode = arrayMode(array);
  const mean = arrayMean(array);

  return mode === mean;
}

function arrayMode(array) {
  const frequencies = new Map();

  for (const value of array) {
    const currentCount = frequencies.has(value) ? frequencies.get(value) : 0;
    frequencies.set(value, currentCount + 1);
  }

  let highestCount = 0;
  let mostOccurringValue;

  for (const [value, count] of frequencies) {
    if (count >= highestCount) {
      highestCount = count;
      mostOccurringValue = value;
    }
  }

  return mostOccurringValue;
}

function arrayMean(array) {
  return array.reduce((sum, value) => sum + value) / array.length;
}
```

Now, answering some of your questions:

> Was using a counts variable necessary?

Yes and no. In order to calculate the mode of a list of numbers, you need to know the number of occurrences for each number. However, it is possible to determine the mode *while* counting the occurences; thus, allowing you to calculate the mode without explicitly storing the occurences. To keep the code simple, I opted for not combining these steps.

> Are all variable keywords (const & let) optimal?

Probably not. You are using `const` and `let`. There is very, very little reason to also still use `var` at all. Most variables are assigned only once and can be defined using `const`. Some variables have to be declared using `let` because they’re (re-)assigned later.

> Is it wise to include comments to describe what the code does?

Yes. Take my code for example. Is there something you don’t understand? Then it could’ve maybe explained with a comment. You used a `reduce` function in your code which I often find hard to read. You need to ask yourself: Is my code dealing with a complex problem that needs explaining or is it just written in a hardly readable fashion? A complex problem is best explained with comments. Code which is hard to read and thus hard to reason about is better fixed by making it more readable and obvious.

> Was declaring the mode variable before assigning its value the best way? Its value depends on a condition

No, it wasn’t. The mode of a list of numbers always exists although it might not be unique. Therefor its value does not logically depend on a condition.

Comment: VERY helpful, thank you. I'll note all of these useful points down. Also I like how you used a for of loop and a new Map to count the number of instances in each array - I'll definitely be copying this trick!

Answer (score 1):

### Too complex

As the issue of complexity has not come up and as the functions complexity is O(n<sup>2</sup>) for a problem that can be solved in O(n) where n is length of `arr`, I must point out some of the flaws.

The code comments show all the iterations for a worst case argument `[2,4,6,8,12,14,16,18,10,10]` the return will be `1`. (`**` is exponential operator)

```
function meanMode(arr) {
    let uniqueVals = Array.from(new Set(arr));        // << array iteration * 2
    let counts = uniqueVals.map(function (c, i, a) {  // << outer iteration
            return arr.filter(function (c2) {         // << inner iteration **2
                return c2 == c
            }).length
        });
    if (arr.every(sameValues)) {                      // << array iteration
        return 0;
    } else {
        var mode;
        if ((counts.filter(function (x) {             // << outer iteration
                    return x == (Math.max(...counts)) // << inner iteration **2 to get max
                }).length) == 1) {

            // Next line has nested iteration **2 to get max again
            mode = uniqueVals[counts.indexOf(Math.max(...counts))]; 
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
        const mean = (arr.reduce(function (a, c) {    // << array iteration
                return a + c
            })) / (arr.length);

        if (mode == mean) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    function sameValues(c, i, a) {
        return c == a[0];
    }
}
```

Not only are the 3 instances of iteration at O(n<sup>2</sup>) unneeded, you use `Array.filter` to count!! :( ...  Use `Array.reduce` to count so you don't need to allocate memory each time you add 1.

There are also repeated iterations that compute the same value. `Math.max(...counts)` requires one full iteration of `counts` each time it is called and you call it in the worst case 2n times.

Even when you add these optimisations (`Array.reduce` rather than `Array.filter` and calculate max once) and gain about 50% performance you are still at O(n<sup>2</sup>).

### In a single pass O(n)

Using a `counts = new Map();` and a single iteration you can compute the `sum` to get the mean (after iteration), count each items frequency (via the map), and as you count the frequency you can keep a record of the top two max counts and the current max `mode`.

After the iteration compute the `mean` from the `sum` divide the `arr.length`, check if `mode` is equal to `mean` and if it is check that the top two frequencies are not equal to return 1 (or true).

An example of O(n) solution tuned for performance. (has optimisation that give an advantage if there are many sequences of the same value)

```
function isMeanMode(arr) {
    const counts = new Map();
    var i, prevMaxVal, item, maxA = -1, maxB = -1, index = 0, max = 1, sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {  // Only one iteration O(n)
        const val = arr[i];
        const item = counts.get(val);
        sum += val;
        if (item) { 
            item.count++;
            while (val === arr[i + 1]) { // for quick count of sequences
                i++; 
                item.count++;
                sum += val;
            }
            if (max <= item.count) {
                max = item.count;
                if (prevMaxVal !== val) { // tracks the top two counts
                    maxB = maxA;          // if maxA and maxB are the same
                    maxA = max;           // after iteration then 2 or more mode vals
                } else { maxA = max }
                index = i;
                prevMaxVal = val;
            }

        } else { counts.set(val, {count : 1}) }
    }
    if (counts.size === arr.length || maxB !== -1 && maxA === maxB) { return 0 }
    return arr[index] === sum / arr.length ? 1 : 0;
}
```

The above solution has a performance increase from 2 orders of magnitude + faster for large random arrays, to 3-4 times faster for very small arrays.